# grammar - emphasis and inversion

Tags: infinitives

Please tell me which one is more correct "What I want to do **is to go there**" or "What I want to do **is go there**".

I'm really confused about this. And I also want to know where to leave out "to" when putting emphasis on verb like this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They both sound perfectly correct to me, and with no difference in meaning.

Note that the version without *to* only works when the subject contains a *do* that the *go* can correspond to. For example, we can say "What I want is to go there", but we cannot say *"What I want is go there."